# VS2008 Shortcut to Move Tabs across Tab Groups

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to move tabs from one tab group to another in Visual Studio 2008? If not, how do I create a macro/command to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one by default but you can add one in Tools > Options > Keyboard, type 'TabGroup' in the 'Show commands containing' box and then setting a keyboard shortcut for the Window.MoveToNextTabGroup or Window.MoveToPreviousTabGroup items.

Answer (score 3):

Or simply, you can use :

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>

Often I find with menu entry keyboarding, if you get used to it, you will be able to use it on  other peoples computers without having to set key-bindings.